# Displaying the ≥ and ≤ ASCII characters in a C Application

Tags: c, character-encoding, ascii, extended-ascii

I am currently writing a C application and I need to display the following symbols in the terminal : **≥** and **≤**

Their ASCII character codes are `242` and `243` but I can't get them to be displayed in the DOS terminal.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: The font your terminal uses might not correspond exactly to ASCII, and there likely isn't a standard way of making it so. Be prepared to either work with something in Boost, or platform-specific code.

Comment: Pedantic point: ASCII encodes characters only up to 127 (0x7F).  Beyond that, characters at code points are implementation-specific. You're speaking of code page 437 (which does have ≥ and ≤ at points 242 and 243).

Comment: If you're on a modern system, use Unicode strings and wprintf (and variants). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("\xf2\n");
```

If that doesn't work, it's because of DOS and code pages.  Try playing with the `CHCP` command.  You're strolling into locales/platform-specific/give-up-now territory.

Comment: still nothing with `printf("\xf2\n");` ...an equals sign (=) is displayed

Comment: This means you're using code page 850 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) which does not encode the ≥ or ≤ glyphs.

Comment: Try changing to code page 437 with chcp (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 7):

These are not in ASCII nor in LATIN1 for instance.

Comment: They aren't even in CP1252, the normal Windows code page, AFAICS.  They look like U+2264 and U+2265 in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

What DOS terminal? If you're compiling to a 32-bit (or 64-bit) binary under Windows, as I'm sure you are, then it's just a console window.

I believe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686036(VS.85).aspx) is the simplest way to set the code page of a console window. It's up to you whether to use code page 437 or a unicode code page (such as UTF-8, which is 65001), but I would suggest Unicode as it will give you more flexibility if you need it later.